# Regex to Match IP from .txt file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

i need to pick Ip address from a .txt file and create a list of those.

i have written the code but not getting the desired result.Have gone through answers that are posted in StackOverflow related to it.

```
import sys    
import re

def get_up_ip():    
    ip = []    
    fp = open('./output1.txt', 'r')    
    for line in fp:    
        if re.match(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', line.splitlines()[2]):    
                ip.append(line.split()[2])    
    return ip    


get_up_ip()
```

**output1.txt** :

```
sw3# show end
----------------------------------------------------------------
 Node 10 (fs-az4-10)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Legend:
 s - arp              O - peer-attached    a - local-aged       S - static
 V - vpc-attached     p - peer-aged        M - span             L - local
 B - bounce           H - vtep
+-----------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
      VLAN/                           Encap           MAC Address       MAC Info/       Interface
      Domain                          VLAN            IP Address        IP Info
+-----------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+
sw:swSer                                     143.252.78.9                      tunnel165
sw:swSer                                  171.252.232.229 a                    tunnel1
sw:swSer                                   17.252.232.77 p                    tunnel1
sw:swSer                                  9.252.193.109 a                    tunnel3
apic#
```

**Desired Result :**

```
ip = ['143.252.78.9','171.252.232.229','17.252.232.77','9.252.193.109']
```

Comment: I see the desired result, but what results are you getting right now?

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp worked for me, just had to adjust line.split()[2] to line.split[1]

```
import sys    
import re

def get_up_ip():    
    ip = []    
    fp = open('output1.txt', 'r')    
    for line in fp:
      if len(line.split()) > 1:
        if re.match(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', line.split()[1]):    
          ip.append(line.split()[1])    

    return ip    

print 'Result:'
print get_up_ip()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code !
It is working fine.

```
import sys    
import re

def get_up_ip():    
    ip = []    
    fp = open('output.txt', 'r')    
    f = fp.read()

    obj = re.findall(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[ ]', f)
    return obj

print get_up_ip()
```

**Output :**

```
['143.252.78.9', '171.252.232.229', '17.252.232.77', '9.252.193.109']
```